# Imagemagick's convert output is small when page format is specified

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I have these 2 JPEG's and I join them into a single pdf with the following command:

```
convert -compress JPEG -quality 90 -page A4 1.jpg 2.jpg doc.pdf
```

However the resulting document's size is only 50x71 mm, you can see it on the following image. This happens with every `-page` format. It works well if I don't specify a `-page`.

[image: Full size capture]

(No, this capture is not scaled down to fit in the question).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know why this happens, but it turns out that I have to also specify a pixel density (DPI) using the `-density` command:

```
convert -compress JPEG -quality 90 -page A4 -density 72 1.jpg 2.jpg doc.pdf
```

I had to choose 72 because that was the only density that gave me the proper A4 size (210x297). Manually specifying 300 would give me the same small document: 300 is the DPI with which I scanned my images.

Comment: Worked for `jpg` input files, but not for `png`. For `png` i also had to specify `-units PixelsPerInch`.

Comment: PDFs use 1/72 inch as a internal unit. Specifying `-density 72` does not mean that you get a super low resolution PDF. The resolution is just needed to compute the correct A4 size in PDF units. Images inside the PDF can have a higher resolution.